# multithreading with java swing for a simple 2d animation

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

my final goal for this application is to animate several items in the same JPanel at a different speed using a thread for each item.the first part is done however the items move at the same speed and i have no idea on how to fix this problem.

```
package javagamestutos;



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable {


    private Star star;
    private Thread animator;
    ArrayList<Star> items=new ArrayList<Star>();


    public Board() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        star=new Star(25,0,0);
        Star star2=new Star(50,20,25);
        items.add(star2);
        items.add(star);
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        animator = new Thread(this);
        animator.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;



        for (Star s : this.items) {
            g2d.drawImage(s.starImage, s.x, s.y, this);
        }


        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true){
            try {
                for (Star s : this.items) {
                    s.move();
                }
                repaint();

                Thread.sleep(star.delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

here is the star class wich is the moving item.

```
package javagamestutos;

import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author fenec
 */
public class Star {
    Image starImage;
    int x,y;
    int destinationX=200,destinationY=226;
    boolean lockY=true;
    int delay;


    public Star(int delay,int initialX,int initialY){
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("star.png"));
        starImage = ii.getImage();
        x=initialX;
        y=initialY;
        this.delay=delay;
    }


    void moveToX(int destX){
        this.x += 1;
    }


    boolean validDestinatonX(){
        if(this.x==this.destinationX){
                this.lockY=false;
                return true;
            }
        else
            return false;
    }

    void moveToY(int destY){
        this.y += 1;
    }


    boolean validDestinatonY(){
        if(this.y==this.destinationY)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void move(){

        if(!this.validDestinatonX() )
            x+=1;
        if(!this.validDestinatonY() && !this.lockY)
            y+=1;

        /*if(!this.validDestinatonY())
            y+=1;
        */
    }


}
```

and here is the skeleton of the animation that extends a JFrame :

```
package javagamestutos;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Skeleton extends JFrame {

public Skeleton() {
        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Stars");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 280);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Skeleton();
    }
}
```

do you have any idea how to achieve my goals?am i using threads proprely?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're invoking the "move" method at a fixed rate specified by the delay of the first "start"

```
  Thread.sleep(star.delay);
```

So if you move them a little every "n" milliseconds, they will seems to move at the same peace.

If you want them to move at different speed, you have to move them in different thread  ( you are using only one now )  Bear in mind the comment by omry,

**EDIT**

I did something similar just recently

I have two different things so animate so I have two timers ( timers use threads underneath, but they can repeat the execution code every fixed rate  ).

The first apply the text to a JLabel every second ( 1000 ms )

```
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
        public void run(){      
            setText();
        }
    }, 0, 1000 );
```

And other change the displaying image every 10 seconds ( 10,000 ms )

```
    final Timer imageTimer = new Timer();
    imageTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            setImage();
        }
    }, 0, 10000 );
```

I have a video of the result here:

[image]

For more advanced ( and nice ) time management you MUST take a look at the ["Timing Framework"](http://www.google.com/search?q=timing+framework) project which adds additional capabilities to timers.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. :) Could use the a single thread, but use, say a priority queue to find the next star to move, or some other random algorithm (like calculating position from time, rather than storing position).

Answer (score 1):

You should be painting in the AWTDispatchThread.  To do that you will want to use something like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);` This applies not only to your animation, but to the creation and setting visible of your `JFrame` as well. Failing to do this could result in deadlocks with the painting thread. Also, when moving your painting operations into the `SwingUtilites` methods, you will not want to include any `while(true)` loops, as that will commandeer your painting thread.

Comment: "your Board is not a Runnable, so your animator = new Thread(this) shouldn't compile."

er... yes it is.  `public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable`

Comment: Yes, I edited as you were typing your comment.  I saw it once you reformatted.  Too bad we can upvote post edits.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Swing components should be used from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). `repaint` is one of the methods that is supposedly okay to use off EDT. However, your `Star` is not and should not be thread-safe.

The easiest approach is to go for EDT-only (at least to start with). Instead of using `Thread` use `javax.swing.Timer` which fires on the EDT.

Misc comments: There should be no need for your `paint` method to dispose of the graphics object sent to it, or for it to sync using `Toolkit`. The component need not be set to double-buffered, but should be set opaque (`JPanel` is not guaranteed to be opaque). You should just extend `JComponent` instead of `JPanel`, as this is not a panel. It's generally not a great idea for outer classes to implement `Runnable`. Prefer private variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at the open source library [trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident) which does just that, its author, Kirill Grouchnikov is well-known in the Swing world (he is the author of the famous Substance look & feel).

Trident should help you solve the problem of having different objects move at different speeds, without having to create one thread per object (which is a problem in the end).

Answer (score -1):

if you are sure you want to paint in the threads, you can use :

```
update(getGraphics());
```

instead of repaint.
this is generally considered bad practice, as you normally paint stuff in the AWT thread.

Comment: @You are right about that, but that's not the reason why they move at the same speed.

Comment: right.
I think you problem is that you sleep a constant time for each iteration.
what you want is to move your object a variable distance (you can pass dx and dy in the ctor) and sleep a constant time (say 40ms for 25 fps).